# Adding longpress event in react native

Tags: react-native

I have one input box, through which I am adding some text, on longpress I have to make the added fields as editable, how can I do that in react native.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your filed clickable without seeing a buton then you should use touchableopacity.
Try this;

```
<TouchableOpacity onLongPress={this._onLongPress}>
   <Input/>
</TouchableOpacity>

_onLongPress = () => {
    this.setState({
        makeEditableFunction: true
    })
}
```